# Nodejs Express keeps serving the same file to all requests

Tags: node.js

So i have an express app and in the **app.js** i have this:

```
app.use('/index', function (req, res, next){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
   }

app.get('/script.js',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/script.js');
```

and after starting the server and type **localhost:3000/index** and the app works fine but here comes the problem..
when i change the first **app.use()** function to:

```
app.use('/', function (req, res, next){}
```

so that i don't have to type the index part in the URL, all the next get requests respond with **index.html** page and i tried adding

```
res.end(); after res.sendFile();
```

but no other response gets sent after that, how can i solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/` route is acting as a wildcard and capturing all requests, which means that anything not matching a route defined BEFORE this route will be caught by it. You have two options here:

1. Change `app.use` to `app.get` so that you are explicitly only matching `/` (and only with a GET method)
2. Move the route to the **bottom** of all of your routes

As explained on the Express.js API docs for `app.use` [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use):

> A route will match any path, which follows its path immediately with a “/”. For example: app.use('/apple', ...) will match “/apple”, “/apple/images”, “/apple/images/news”, and so on.